# Cachegrind not showing function-level results?

Tags: linux, performance, valgrind, kcachegrind, cachegrind

I am profiling my C++ application with Valgrind's Cachegrind, using this terminal line:

```
valgrind --branch-sim=yes --tool=cachegrind ./myProgram
```

and from the online guides I have seen this should automatically present function-level profiling results. However, I am only getting the program-level results.

What else do I need to specify to see the results for each function?

**UPDATE**

Ok I needed to run this:

```
cg_annotate cachegrind.out.XXXX
```

to get the function-level results.

Comment: are you profiling a php application?

Comment: @PacketTracer sorry C++, have edited Q to include this now.

Comment: ok, I use it on php, and you need to enable the profiler in your debug extension to log to files, but I think this is not needed in C++. Maybe you can check those GDB options.

Comment: same issue as you met..